# cómo agregar setTimeout a addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, css

quiero tapar con una animación css el movimiento repentino que hace javascript insertBefore, retrasandolo con settimeout un segundo para que le dé tiempo a css a realizar un efecto de movimiento suave.

Hice un div que se va para atrás. Capture los div, con un bucle for les agrege un addEventListener para cuando hagan clicks en los div el insertBefore mueva el div B a la columna A o el div A a la B. Le agregué settimeout de varias formas sin éxito:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <style>

        .frame{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            font: bold 400% sans-serif;
            color: white;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .frame.a{
            background-color: brown;
        }
        
        .frame.b{
            background-color: purple;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div id="gallery">
    
        <div class = "frame a" >A</div>
        
        <div class = "frame b" >B</div>
        
</div>
</body>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

const frames = gallery.querySelectorAll('.frame');

for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
    
  frames[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      
      //function() {setTimeout( flip, 1000 )};
      
      //function flip() {
          
          if ( this.className == "frame b" ) {
        
              gallery.insertBefore( this, this.previousElementSibling );
            
          }else{
          
              gallery.insertBefore( this, this.previousElementSibling );
          
          };
          
      //};
      
  });
  
};

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
const frames = gallery.querySelectorAll('.frame');

for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
    
  frames[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      let self = this;
      setTimeout(function() { flip(self); }, 1000);
  });
};

function flip(elemento) {   
    if ( elemento.className == "frame b" ) {
        gallery.insertBefore( elemento, elemento.previousElementSibling );    
    }else{
        gallery.insertBefore( elemento, elemento.previousElementSibling );   
    };   
};
```

```css
   .frame{
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            font: bold 400% sans-serif;
            color: white;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .frame.a{
            background-color: brown;
        }
        
        .frame.b{
            background-color: purple;
        }
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
    
        <div class = "frame a" >A</div>
        
        <div class = "frame b" >B</div>
        
</div>
```